# Neither \boldsymbol{} nor \bm{} work in beamer class

Tags: math-mode, bold, boldmath

I need to typeset some variables in math mode that are bold *and* slanted. I tried to use `\boldsymbol` (`\usepackage{amsbsy}`) and `\bm` (`\usepackage{bm}`). However, neither of them work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsbsy}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \frametitle{Bold}

    \begin{itemize}
     \item $\boldsymbol{R}$ versus $R$
     \item $\bm{R}$ versus $R$
    \end{itemize}

}

\end{document}
```

The output is as following:

[image]

**Any suggestions? What did I do wrong?**

Comment: Are you getting any missing font shape warnings? Maybe there is no slanted bold

Comment: @MaxNoe You're right. I get `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined (Font) using \`OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 20.` This seems to be the problem. However, is there a work around?

Comment: Which TeX distribution, and which version of `beamer`, do you use? (I have no problem with bold-italics under MikTeX2.9.)

Comment: Please update your packages. Both versions run for me, too.

Comment: I am using texlive 2013 on a machine with Ubuntu 14.04 (LTS) - Based on the official repositories this is the most recent version of texlive for my Ubuntu. It seems that this could be very well the problem. However, I am somehow reluctant to update this very stable system since I am still working of different projects that might rely on certain software versions. In the past I sometimes had problems with updates (i.e., could not compile some documents, statistical analysis resulted in slightly different findings etc.). Thank you anyway!

Comment: You did nothing wrong; the problem is that you have an outdated TeX Live. You can work around the problem by adding `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue with TeX Live 2012, not with 2013.

Upgrading to a current TeX Live would be best. A workaround is available anyway:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} % but utf8 would be better
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bold}

    \begin{itemize}
     \item $\boldsymbol{R}$ versus $R$
     \item $\bm{R}$ versus $R$
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Loading `amsbsy` is useless, as `bm` clobbers the `\boldsymbol` command making it equivalent to `\bm`.

Avoid the `\frame{...}` syntax and favor

```
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Splendid. This works well. Concerning the TeX live distribution, I definitively have the 2013 version installed: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`.

Comment: But maybe not all the fonts! TeX Live is scattered into multiple sub packages in the ubuntu repos. Just install the current TeX Live from tug: https://www.tug.org/texlive/

Answer (score -1):

Beamer redefines a number of fonts by default. If you want to suppress these definitions, just add this to your preamble:

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

It will suppress the definitions modified by Beamer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How does this solve the given issue? Can you please explain?